# Google maps js api map not loading in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I moved a page from a standalone html page into a php template for wordpress. The page has a google map in it that is no longer loading. It's set to height 100% in the css, but when the page loads, it is at 0px, and when I check the sources I do not see all of the map files. Here's what my sources look like on the wordpress page.

[image]

And what it looks like on the original site.

[image]

The scripts are being loaded right before the footer, directly in the template page, although I have tried to move them in to the footer.php file, which didn't change anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/resources/js/home.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I know this is probably not ideal for loading this in Wordpress, but it's a rush job to put up a temporary page, so I don't really have time to implement everything the right way. Here's my JS in home.js

```
var markers = [],
        map,
        openingTimeline = new TimelineLite(),
        neighborhoods = [
          {lat: 40.037745   ,   lng:    -75.539315  },
            {lat:   33.678238   ,   lng:    -112.101291 },
            {lat:   43.592121   ,   lng:    -116.19333  },
            {lat:   32.638644   ,   lng:    -97.304323  },
            {lat:   45.403618   ,   lng:    -122.562171 },
            {lat:   33.857066   ,   lng:    -117.903592 },
            {lat:   43.615218   ,   lng:    -116.200036 },
            {lat:   45.052629   ,   lng:    -92.806624  },
            {lat:   44.871993   ,   lng:    -93.425385  },
            {lat:   36.81239    ,   lng:    -76.065197  },
            {lat:   41.611046   ,   lng:    -90.57509   },
            {lat:   32.78   ,   lng:    -96.8   },
            {lat:   32.993987   ,   lng:    -97.053279  },
            {lat:   46.817458   ,   lng:    -96.86393   },
            {lat:   36.351651   ,   lng:    -94.180028  },
            {lat:   41.573418   ,   lng:    -90.564322  },
            {lat:   33.047885   ,   lng:    -97.0606    },
            {lat:   31.204645   ,   lng:    121.480034  },
            {lat:   22.286931   ,   lng:    114.141124  },
            {lat:   43.596035   ,   lng:    -116.176386 },
            {lat:   33.081626   ,   lng:    -96.831755  },
            {lat:   41.985225   ,   lng:    -88.007874  },
            {lat:   32.78   ,   lng:    -96.8   },
            {lat:   41.660091   ,   lng:    -86.26071   },
            {lat:   39.949476   ,   lng:    -91.397037  },
            {lat:   38.583003   ,   lng:    -121.514606 },
            {lat:   37.69727    ,   lng:    -121.9331   },
            {lat:   39.583579   ,   lng:    -104.857137 },
            {lat:   38.951881   ,   lng:    -76.834091  },
            {lat:   29.724601   ,   lng:    -95.54848   },
            {lat:   43.59849    ,   lng:    -116.177244 },
            {lat:   37.698696   ,   lng:    -121.928664 },
            {lat:   45.403618   ,   lng:    -122.562171 },
            {lat:   47.620012   ,   lng:    -122.17501  },
            {lat:   33.184634   ,   lng:    -97.099463  },
            {lat:   36.346182   ,   lng:    -94.187043  },
            {lat:   38.758384   ,   lng:    -90.453725  },
            {lat:   42.011992   ,   lng:    -71.050855  },
            {lat:   38.602137   ,   lng:    -90.400849  },
            {lat:   38.95972    ,   lng:    -76.714415  },
            {lat:   34.005726   ,   lng:    -118.151419 },
            {lat:   41.133795   ,   lng:    -104.825084 },
            {lat:   32.923811   ,   lng:    -96.798133  },
            {lat:   36.365584   ,   lng:    -94.21815   },
            {lat: -37.832379, lng: 144.960433}
        ];

$(document).ready(function($) {

    // Start opening animation
    openingTimeline
    // show body
    .set('body', {opacity: 1})
    // fade show Why Ivie & Tagline
    .staggerFrom('#why-ivie, #tagline', 0.7, {y: -20, opacity: 0, ease:Sine.easeInOut}, 0.4, "+=1")
    .add("showMap", "+=1.5")
    //  hide text
    .to('#why-ivie, #tagline', 0.5, {y: 40, opacity: 0}, "showMap")
    //  hide overlay
    .to('.overlay', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0}, "showMap+=0.5")
    .from('#map-slider', 0.4, {opacity: 0, onComplete: function(){
        dropPins()
    }}, "showMap+=0.5")
    .from('#slider', 0.5, {marginTop: '-20px', opacity: 0}, "+=1.5")
    ;

});

function initMap() {

    // Disallow drag on mobile
    var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 480 ? true : false;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: isDraggable,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
  });

  // Center map in between California LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932) and New York LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)
  map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932), new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)))

}

// Animate pins dropping
function dropPins() {
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 20);
  }
}

// Animate pins dropping
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: '/wp-content/themes/ivie2014/resources/img/marker.png',
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

// Fade items into view on scroll
$(document).ready(function() {

    TweenLite.set('.animate-me', {y: 40, opacity: 0})

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $('body').scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.animate-me').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + 100;
            var bottom_of_window = $('body').scrollTop() + $('body').height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                TweenLite.to($(this), 1, {y: 0, opacity: 1})
            }

        });

    });

});
```

There are no console errors, or anything else noticeable besides the missing files from the google api. I have also logged some text from within all the functions in home.js and they are definitely being called. I keep thinking there must be something wrong with my API key, but I have created a new one twice, with no change in the issues. The old API key works fine on the other site that we pulled this page from.

Comment: Did you try to use `wp_enqueue_script()` in your `functions.php`? did you setup priority?

Comment: I did not try to enqueue the scripts. Like I said I don't have much time to set them up that way. I do know that the home,js file is being loaded first, however. I tried switching it the other way and I got the error "initMaps is not a function"

Comment: Does anyone know if it takes time for a new API key to become valid? Maybe my key is too new?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Did you try to play with the `async` or `defer` values?

Comment: I have tried removing them, if that's what you mean, to no effect,

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the way all your scripts are being loaded, the sequence to be specific. How about only `async` or only `defer`?
Anyway, `wp_enqueue_script` is the correct form to load scripts in Wordpress...

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Ensure that the parent div of the map has height determined in order for the height 100% to work or try setting a static height e.g `height: 400px;`
2. Better use `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue google maps library
3. Ensure map is loaded with something like:

`google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
  console.log("map loaded");
 });`

4. Try force redraw the map after load `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')` if for some reason the map is glitching.

I hope any of these will help.